# IIS7 URL rewrite - Path has question mark (not query string)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-7, rewrite

I need to redirect this:

http://www.example.com/?/careers/

to this:

http://www.example.com/jobs/

But IIS7 URL rewrite does not recognize the question mark, even if I try to escape it. Is this possible?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162946/iis-7-url-rewrite-doesnt-work-if-the-url-has-a-question-mark-in-it help?

Comment: I already knew that IIS interprets query strings differently but this is followed by a slash and is not interpreted by the browser as a query string. Therefore, is there any way to treat it differently within URL rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question mark is considered the beginning of the query string.

One way to rewrite this could be:

```
<rule name="serverfault" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/jobs" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="/careers" />
    </conditions>
</rule>
```

This rules matches any requests whatsoever and then adds a condition where the query string needs to match `/careers`

Comment: That looks like it might work. I'll test it out tomorrow. Thanks!